# Cisco - client can ping but router not

Tags: router, ipv6, tunnel

I configured a HE.net IPv6 Tunnel on my router which has two WAN ports. The strange thing is that all clients are able to ping IPv6 hosts on Internet, but my router cannot ping anyone.

Here's the configuration:

```
version 15.1
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname gateway
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 4 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
!
aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!         
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
ip source-route
ip cef
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.10.1 172.16.10.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.10.200 172.16.10.254
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.20.1 172.16.20.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.20.200 172.16.20.254
!
ip dhcp pool A-Group
 network 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 172.16.10.254 
 dns-server 172.16.10.254 
!
ip dhcp pool B-Group
 network 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 172.16.20.254 
 dns-server 172.16.20.254 
!
!
ip domain name internal.xxxxxx.net
ip name-server 2001:4860:4860::8888
ip name-server 2001:470:20::2
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip ddns update method TunnelBroker
 HTTP
  add https://xxxx:xxxxxxxxx@ipv4.tunnelbroker.net/ipv4_end.phptid=xxxxxx
 interval maximum 0 1 0 0
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
crypto pki trustpoint tunnelbroker
 enrollment terminal pem
 revocation-check none
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain tunnelbroker
 certificate ca 01
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    quit
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FGL170311S6
!
!
object-group network PRIVATE-NET 
 host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
!
username xxxxxx password 0 xxxxxxxx
!
!
ip ssh time-out 60
ip ssh authentication-retries 5
!
!
!
!
interface Tunnel0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::2/64
 ipv6 enable
 tunnel source Dialer2
 tunnel mode ipv6ip
 tunnel destination 72.52.104.74
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
 mtu 1496
 no ip address
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 172.16.10.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ipv6 address 2001:xxx:xxx:10::1/64
 ipv6 enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 172.16.20.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ipv6 address 2001:xxx:xxx:20::1/64
 ipv6 enable
!
interface Dialer1
 ip address negotiated
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1
 ppp chap hostname xxxxxxxxxxx
 ppp chap password 0 xxxxxxxxxxx
 ppp pap sent-username xxxxxxxx password 0 xxxxxxx
 ppp ipcp dns request
!
interface Dialer2
 ip ddns update TunnelBroker
 ip address negotiated
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 2
 ppp chap hostname xxxxxx
 ppp chap password 0 xxxxxxx
 ppp pap sent-username xxxxxx password 0 xxxxxx
 ppp ipcp dns request
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip dns server
ip nat inside source route-map dia1-nat interface Dialer1 overload
ip nat inside source route-map dia2-nat interface Dialer2 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer2
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
ip route 72.52.104.74 255.255.255.255 Dialer2
!
ip access-list extended PRIVATE-POOL
 permit ip object-group PRIVATE-NET any
ip access-list extended WAN-POOL
 permit ip any any
!
ipv6 route ::/0 Tunnel0
!
route-map dia2-nat permit 10
 match ip address WAN-POOL
 match interface Dialer2
!         
route-map dia1-nat permit 10
 match ip address PRIVATE-POOL
 match interface Dialer1
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
----omitted----
```

On client side:

```
xxxx$ ping6 google.com
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2001:470:8318:10:dc24:208e:6843:8932 --> 2404:6800:4008:c00::66
16 bytes from 2404:6800:4008:c00::66, icmp_seq=0 hlim=52 time=343.733 ms
16 bytes from 2404:6800:4008:c00::66, icmp_seq=1 hlim=52 time=343.917 ms
16 bytes from 2404:6800:4008:c00::66, icmp_seq=2 hlim=52 time=345.722 ms
^C
--- google.com ping6 statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 343.733/344.457/345.722/0.897 ms
```

On router:

```
gateway#ping 2404:6800:4008:c00::66
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 2404:6800:4008:C00::66, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
gateway#
```

Comment: Not related, but since you have a type 4 password... http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityResponse/cisco-sr-20130318-type4

Answer (score 0):

I removed the multi-wan parts (default router and NAT) and it works... No idea why :-(

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing IPv4 and IPv6. Think of them as totally different protocols like OSPF/EIGRP, they dont talk unless you tell them to. You have to 'think' like a router.